# Drupal 7 Views Slideshow Images Not Appearing

Tags: drupal, module, view, slideshow

I am using this Module along with 'Views Slideshow: Cycle' and am not able to get the images I set up to appear. I am able to get the titles to appear and even transition correctly.

Any thoughts as to what can be done to fix this?

Comment: Please give screen shot of your view here

Answer (score 1):

Usually, all you would need to do is setup a view with a list of content.

**Format**
Format: "Slideshow"
Style: Skin - Default

Slides: Slideshow Type - Cycle (Choose the transition effect you want, I use fade)

Show: "Fields"

**Fields**
Content (Title) - I put "Exclude from display" but it depends what you are looking for.
Content (Image) - Make sure it's not marked as "Exclude from display"
You can do a "Style settings", "Customize field HTML" as well. I put SPAN as element and "image-right" as css class (I think you can put image-left and image-center as well). Maybe that's the part you were missing?

**Sort**
Put a sort, I noticed views hate it when there is none. If you don't care you can just put Global (Random)

**Pager**
Display all items | All items

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the jQuery cycle plugin. Create a directory in sites/all/libraries called jquery.cycle,
and then copy jquery.cycle.all.min.js into it. You can find the plugin at http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle.

Download the plugin from the link and save it in the sites/all/libraries/jquery.cycle with the name jquery.cycle.all.min.js
You will not find the minified version there so just download the full format and name it jquery.cycle.all.min.js. It will work.